# Attribute Assistant not showing errors

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, arcgis-local-government, attribute-assistant

I am using the Attribute Assistant extension in ArcMap 10.5 to validate road name data against a Master Street Names table using the method 'VALIDATE_ATTRIBUTE_LOOKUP'. My issue is that I am 100% certain that at least 1 record is wrong, but when I run the Assistant I get no errors.

I have one file geodatabase with three standalone tables located inside, these are the only files in the geodatabase. The first table is 'all_addresses_2013' which has a field called 'Street2'. The next table is 'MasterStreetName' with a field called 'FULLNAME'. The final table is the 'DynamicValue' table, which uses the method: 'VALIDATE_ATTRIBUTE_LOOKUP' and 'Manual Only' is the only value set to True. Picture attached below.

For the most part the 'Street2' field and 'FULLNAME' field have the same values. My initial test did not return any errors, which I thought strange so I edited one record in 'Street2' to be be complete gibberish as to check the Assistant, but I still didn't get any error message. I then changed one record in the 'FULLNAME' field in the 'MasterStreetName' table to different gibberish word and ran the Assistant again, again no error message. Finally, I changed the 'Field Name' in the 'DynamicValue' table to 'xxxx' (which is not a field in either the 'MasterStreetName' or 'all_addresses-2013' tables) and still nothing.

Between each of these steps I turned the Assistant off then back on, I have tried all of this with the entire 'all_addresses_2013' table selected, just the gibberish record selected, and also some trials with a handful of 10 or 11 records selected.

I am certain I am using the Table/Field name (as opposed to the Alias) this is the only record in my 'DynamicValue' table with the 'Manual Only' field set to True. The page from which I downloaded the extension is listed as being compatible with this version of ArcMap and it was only downlaoded about dour days ago. (http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/) I have been able to use the Assistant before on this computer, but now I am getting no results.

Any ideas?

[image: Sorry if this is hard to read]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: What button did you click to run the Attribute Assistant?

Comment: Is your lookup table in your Map document?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tour, Midavalo! Yes, all three tables are in the map document and to run the Assistant I have been using the 'Run Manual Rules for Selected Features' button.